# same code, different printing order with printf() and write() in different C compilers

Tags: c, cs50

Edit: I simplified the original code.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int     main(void)
{

    printf("printf1\n");
    write(1, "1 should be after printf\n", 25);

    printf("printf2\n");
    write(1, "2 should be after printf\n", 25);

    return 0;
}
```

Unexpected result on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/vHpPNV):

```
1 should be after printf
2 should be after printf
printf1
printf2
```

Expected result on [cs50](https://run.cs50.net/)

```
printf1
1 should be after printf
printf2
2 should be after printf
```

Why is the output order different?

Comment: you're not flushing the output after the printfs.  when it gets flushed is OS dependent.  See [this](/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thank you! You points me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the printf waits for the buffer to be full while write does not do that. If you have a \n (new line character) at the end of your printf, Then it will call write as soon as it encounters the \n. Note that print also calls the write once the buffer is full. write will just outputs the given number of bytes into the terminal, Hence will be faster.

try your code as:

```
printf("i = %d\n", i);
ft_putstr("should be printed right after printf\n");
```

Comment: I tried the code with \n added to the printf, but the ft_putstr()'s contents still comes before printf()'s. You can see the result on http://ideone.com/zGacCM

Comment: I tried it on my local machine. It works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: printf("i = %d\n", i);
            fflush(stdout);
            ft_putstr("should be printed right after printf\n"); this will also work fine. just flush the buffer.